# Insertar en una tabla tantos registros como valores hay en una columna de otra tabla, en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert

Tengo una tabla A con las siguientes columnas:

| ID | tipo |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 1, 2, 3 |
| 02 | 1 |
| 03 | 3, 4 |

La columna `tipo` tiene los diferentes tipos admitidos del `ID` correspondiente separados por comas.
Quisiera saber cómo transformar esto insertando registros en una tabla B, pero con el siguiente formato:

| ID | tipo |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 |
| 01 | 2 |
| 01 | 3 |
| 02 | 1 |
| 03 | 3 |
| 04 | 4 |

Comment: Entiendo que lo quieres insertar en una base de datos, ¿es así? En caso afirmativo, ¿qué base de datos utilizas?

Comment: Sí, también yo, he sido demasiado escueto en las explicaciones. Pido disculpas. Efectivamente @RogerTorné, se trata de hacer un script de inserción en Transact-SQL contra una base de datos SQL Server, leyendo de la tabla A e insertando en la tabla B. También podría generar la tabla A separando en columnas cada uno de los tipos, que ahora están en una sola columna separados por comas, si eso resultase más fácil para general el script. Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función de SQL Server `STRING_SPLIT()`. [Esta función](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) divide el texto del campo indicado (tipo) entre su carácter separador (una coma) generando nuevas filas para cada coincidencia.

```
SELECT ID, value  
FROM TablaOrigen  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tipo, ',');
```

Si lo quieres insertar en otra tabla, utilizas el `INSERT INTO`

```
INSERT INTO TablaDestino (ID, Tipo)
SELECT ID, value  
FROM TablaOrigen  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tipo, ',');
```

Comment: Vaya, más sencillo de lo que parecía. Aún así tengo problemas reconociendo la funcion STRING_SPLIT(), quizás por la versión que tengo instalada 

(Microsoft SQL 
Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) Oct 28 2016 18:17:30)
 
Al final he podido resolverlo transformando inicialmente la tabla para tener una columna por cada tipo en lugar de todos los tipos en la misma columna y separados por comas. Una vez hecho esto, he utilizado un SELECT UNPIVOT 
Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), esta función está disponible desde SQL Server 2016